# add tracking number using paypal tracking api

Tags: node.js, paypal

I'm trying to integrate @paypal tracking API `https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/` into my node app, so I can update paypal tracking information within the app.

I found this sample request on @paypal docs `https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/tracking/v1/#trackers_put`
but how am I gonna use this in my node app ?

```
curl -v -X PUT https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers/8MC585209K746392H-443844607820 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "transaction_id": "8MC585209K746392H",
  "tracking_number": "443844607820",
  "status": "SHIPPED",
  "carrier": "FEDEX"
}'
```

Comment: There are many libraries available for making HTTP requests in node, such as axios, got, or a fetch clone

Comment: @PrestonPHX you mean somethink like this: `https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/17/react-axios-http-post-request-examples`

Comment: That's specific to the React framework, but sure, something like that.